# Java: Overwrite the existing file on server with modified file(excel sheet) using File API

Tags: java, file, file-upload, file-io, filesystems

I have code that is designed to open a local master file, make additions, and save the file both by overwriting the master file and overwriting a write protected copy on an accessible network location.

But I am unable to replace the existing file on server. I have gone through other link on stackoverflow also like this but still no success.

Kndly assist me ! Rgds The code is

```
public class UploadAndSaveExcelAction extends Action

{

public ActionForward execute(

ActionMapping mapping,

ActionForm form,

HttpServletRequest request,

HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception{

UploadAndSaveExcelForm myForm = (UploadAndSaveExcelForm)form;
String target = null;
if (myForm.getTheExcel().getFileName().length() > 0) {
FormFile myFile = myForm.getTheExcel();
  System.out.println("" +myFile);

String fileName  = myFile.getFileName();


byte[] fileData  = myFile.getFileData();

//Get the servers upload directory real path name

 String filePath = getServlet().getServletContext().getRealPath("/")   +"Sheet\SparesUsed.xls";

  /* Save file on the server */
 //create the upload folder if not exists
 File folder = new File(filePath);
 if(folder.exists()){
  System.out.println("Excel Sheet folder is  existed therefore deleted");
   folder.deleteOnExit();


 }
 String filePath1 = getServlet().getServletContext().getRealPath("/") +"Sheet";
 File folder1 = new File(filePath1+"\\" + FileName);
  System.out.println("Excel Sheet afterr delete folder is  "+folder1);
boolean makedirectory=folder1.mkdir();
System.out.println(" Making Directory "+makedirectory);

 if(!fileName.equals("")){  

  System.out.println("Server path for Excel :" +filePath);

 //Create file

 File fileToCreate = new File(filePath, fileName);

 //If file does not exists create file  

 if(!fileToCreate.exists()){

 FileOutputStream fileOutStream = new FileOutputStream(fileToCreate);

 fileOutStream.write(fileData);

 fileOutStream.flush();

 fileOutStream.close();
target ="success";
 } return mapping.findForward(target);}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spoon library.

I know it's been a while since the original post, but one of the more accessible looking Java transformation libraries appears to be Spoon(http://spoon.gforge.inria.fr/).

From the Spoon Homepage(http://spoon.gforge.inria.fr/):

Spoon enables you to transform (see below) and analyze (see example) source code. Spoon provides a complete and fine-grained Java metamodel where any program element (classes, methods, fields, statements, expressions...) can be accessed both for reading and modification. Spoon takes as input source code and produces transformed source code ready to be compiled.

Comment: Mr, Jwalin Sorry I could not get you, what for spoon library used for? I have added code , can you make it understand with reference..

Comment: Spoon library is used to modify and replace file on the server. did you check home page of spoon library. Sample code is also available there.